# SQL to identify all records which have duplicates in a certain column with certain values

Tags: sql, db2

We have data in DB2 something similar as below :

| GUID | ID | Key | SubKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC-123-DEF | 1234567 | 20 | 1 |
| ABC-123-DEF | 1234567 | 22 | 1 |
| ABC-123-DEF | 1234567 | 21 | 2 |
| ABC-123-DEF | 1234568 | 22 | 1 |
| ABC-124-DEF | 1234667 | 21 | 2 |
| ABC-124-DEF | 1234668 | 22 | 2 |
| ABC-125-DEF | 1234767 | 21 | 1 |
| ABC-125-DEF | 1234768 | 22 | 1 |

I want to output with all details only where Subkey condition with 1 is repeating more than once , something as below

| GUID | ID | Key | SubKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC-123-DEF | 1234567 | 20 | 1 |
| ABC-123-DEF | 1234567 | 22 | 1 |
| ABC-123-DEF | 1234567 | 21 | 2 |
| ABC-123-DEF | 1234568 | 22 | 1 |
| ABC-125-DEF | 1234767 | 21 | 1 |
| ABC-125-DEF | 1234768 | 22 | 1 |

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Why is `ABC-123-DEF 1234567 21 2` in the expected output, but not `ABC-124-DEF 1234668 22 2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window aggregation group clause of `SUM(..) OVER (PARTITION BY .. )` along with a conditional such as

```
SELECT GUID, ID, Key, SubKey
  FROM ( SELECT t.*,
                SUM(CASE WHEN SubKey = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY GUID) AS cnt
           FROM t ) tt
 WHERE cnt > 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/TvLSARb6)</kbd>

Comment: A slightly shorter variant: `COUNT(CASE WHEN SubKey = 1 THEN 1 END)` or if boolean is supported in the version: `count(nullif(SubKey=1,0))`

Comment: Thanks @Lennart-SlavaUkraini you're right, the first case is exactly as in MySQL.

Comment: I believe it should work in all DBMS, COUNT does not consider null which is the result if not matched by case

Comment: Speaking of which, this is pretty optimal I think: `sum(SubKey=1)`. The oldest one I could test was Db2 11.1 and it works there: https://dbfiddle.uk/8sQA5-TP

Comment: Very good @Lennart-SlavaUkraini , and this property is exactly used in MySQL too, while not possible within Oracle as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the columns you want to group.

Assuming its the `GUID` column.

```sql
SELECT GUID
FROM THE_TABLE
WHERE SUBKEY = 1
GROUP BY GUID
HAVING COUNT(SUBKEY) > 1
```

Comment: We are expecting GUID list only with SUBKEY is repeated with value 1 multiple times